# Is there any need to call FB.getLoginstatus repeatedly along with subscribing event

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

From localhost I am loading 1 page which neads to check whether any body has logged on facebook.
So I need to check the status repeatedly. I thought subscribing events(auth.login, auth.statuschange) is sufficient. But the event taking 30 mins to get fire after action is taken.
so I implemented my code in following way:

```
        FB.init({
        appId: "472581889444408",
        channel: true,
        channelUrl: "http://localhost/channel/channel.html",
        status: true,
        xfbml: true,
        oauth: true
        }); 
        FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response){
                    alert("login");document.bgColor = 'Teal';});
        FB.Event.subscribe('auth.logout', function(response){alert("log out");document.bgColor = '#FF8FFF';});
        FB.Event.subscribe('auth.statusChange', function(response){alert("status changed");document.bgColor = '#ff8889';});

        window.setInterval(FB.getLoginStatus, 30000);
```

Can anybody please suggest better way to do this

Comment: If I just subscribe the event and dont call getLoginstatus periodically then behavior is different(log out alert is shown after 30mins from logging off)

Comment: If we are subscribing to event then whats the need of explicitly checking the status.